# Telas cortadas do Delphi em Windows 8 (intermitente)

Tags: delphi, windows-8

**Como fazer para não 'cortar' as Telas de Delphi no Windows 8?**

O sistema estava rodando certinho no Windows XP. Passei para Windows 8 e percebi que algumas telas vêm cortadas (dá para ler a parte de cima e a parte de baixo). Verificando a relação de componentes x problemas, aparentemente são telas com TExDBGrid.

Comment: Executando hora clica, chama a janela certa, hora clica chama a janela errada. Verificado tb com meu colega que está em outra maquina e migrou do WXP para W8 e dá a mesma coisa.

Comment: Mudei o nome do controle porque é o único controle Delphi semelhante que achei. Se realmente era o outro nome, dê uma referência sobre ele.

Comment: - Estou verificando se é algo relacionado a skin. Usando a VclSkin. 
- Pelo que ví é a ExDBGrid mesmo. 
TExDBGrid
ExDBGrid Component Suite Version 3.9 - TexDBGrid
http://www.gjl-software.co.uk

Obrigado pelo intuito de ajudar.

Comment: Continuo desconfiando da VclSkin Delphi2006 Package
(VclSkin\WinSkinD2006.bpl) Assim que puder investigo mais

Comment: Qual a versão do delphi você está utilizando? Se for o Delphi 7 vai acontecer isso mesmo
porque o windows 8 e windows XP tem diferenças gigantescas...
Recomendo que troque a versão do delphi para qualquer versão XE, mas, de preferência 4 ou 5.
Mas eu recomendo que troque não só porque está bugando no windows 8, mas, também porque nós programadores temos que estar nos atualizando para melhor atender nossos clientes, e também programar mais rápido...

Comment: Mas muitas vezes os sistemas vem de anos, décadas alguns, instalado em vários clientes etc. Conheço empresas que programa em Delphi 7, outras até em 6... Está atendendo as necessidades dos clientes? Ótimo. Mas concordo que sempre que possível a fila tem que andar. Xii, isso pode levar uma discussão grande que pode ficar para um outro tópico. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

É a skin que esta com problema. Ela **não funciona com o Aero Glass do Windows 8**, tanto que **desabilitando as telas voltam ao normal (não cortadas)**:

```
Em oncreate do form:
  skcPrincipal.Active := True; //sk'C'
  skdPrincipal.Active := True; //sk'D'
```

Pelo que investigamos, esta skin naturalmente não suporta Aero Glass (não existia estas frescuras, hehehehe), .: a pessoa, no Windows 7 w7 deveria desligar o Aero. Mas no Windows 8 não tem como desligar.

**Estamos procurando uma nova skin**, se alguém tiver uma sugestão agradeço. O duro que a skin faz parte da identidade visual do sistema...

Obrigado a todos.

Comment: Aero glass não existe mais no windows 8. Mudar a versão do Delphi para uma versão mais nova habilitaria novas skins, entretanto, o problema de "cortar a tela" ainda acontecerá se sua aplicação não for DPI-aware.